# patterns of possible hacking attempts in the given web log file

Tags: python, regex

Wildcard `*` : The `*` character (asterisk) is often used by attackers as an
argument to a system command. Below is an example:

`"GET /*.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 488 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"`

This request is asking for all text files within the directory of the target
website. Requests like these can often be used to gather a list of log files,
along with other important files. Not a lot of web applications use this
character in a valid request so this makes an asterisk stand out in logs.

I was trying to extract data from log file for example:-

`GET /*.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 488 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"`

in which HTTP is attached with some files like `.png`,`.jpg` etc. I have done the code below but unable to get the results.Can anybody help me out of this?

```py
import re

log_file = input("Enter file name: ")

# with open(log_file,"r") as f:
#   sample_file = f.readlines()

f = open(log_file, "r")

pattern = re.compile(r"(GET|POST)(https:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*\/?\S")

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if re.search(pattern, line):
        print(line.strip())

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Start simple. For example, why wouldn't `(GET|POST).+\*` work? That flags anything with an asterisk in it. If it's too broad in some way (asterisk somewhere else isn't suspect), then narrow it down to exclude those cases.

Perhaps the asterisk needs to be in the requested URL only. We notice that the URL is followed by `HTTP/1.1` (more generally `HTTP/\d`), so we could say:

`(GET|POST).+\*.+HTTP/\d`

meaning anything with an asterisk between `GET|POST` and `HTTP/1.1`

Should it be anything with an asterisk followed by a valid extension? Then how about:

`(GET|POST).+\*\.[a-z]{2,6} HTTP/\d`

And build it out from there.

Btw the forward slash `/` does not need to be escaped in regular expressions. `https://` is valid RE.